# joomla extension to create forms

Tags: php, forms, html, plugins, joomla2.5

i want a dynamic form which has a facility to add text field or any field in any order ( as a grid, vertically, in a row) and user(user of that form not developer) should be able to add rows of text field.
Please suggest me some open source/free plugin.
So guide me how can create that type of plugin. i searched it in google but could not find any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try Fox Contact Form.  It is a free form creating plugin for Joomla.  You can customize fields and change ordering and layout.

It adds an extremely small "Made By ...." at the bottom of the form, but that can be removed with a purchased license, though that isn't necessary because it is hardly noticed.

You can find the plugin http://www.fox.ra.it/joomla-extensions/fox-contact-form.html

Comment: thanks for replying derek. I have used this plugin for one of my site, it has limited number for fields. this time i want unlimited number of fields to be added in any order and one grid of text boxes where initially i will show only one row, but user should be able to add more rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try Chronoforms.It is highly customizable with both Plug-in and Modules.Check the demo and use
http://www.chronoengine.com/component/content/article/1-latest/2083-chronoforms-for-j16-is-out.html

Comment: but i want some more things :1. text boxes grid in which user can any number of rows and 2. different forms in tabs. is it possible with this plugin??..if yes can you please tell me how..some tutorials which will help me in achieving this

Comment: I think this extension will meet ur requirement.It allows users to create custom forms with custom fields.http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/crm/19640 If not then check the CRM page  http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/crm